# Fonts in texlive 2022 appear not to be found (overleaf / mac os / mac os home brew version)

Tags: fonts, texlive, texlive2022

I have some custom latex articles forms which use the LobsterTwo font in certain places. I noticed for this particular font that it does not work, neither on my Mac, nor on overleaf. (I re-installed texlive 2022 from homebrew, but it shows the same result.) When compiling a document with pdflatex it does not give me an error message, but warnings and it substitutes a different font.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\newcommand*{\LobsterTwo}{\fontfamily{LobsterTwo-LF}\selectfont}

\title{\LobsterTwo{\fontsize{80}{60}\selectfont Texte}}
%\author{{\LobsterTwo Alexander Deisting} }
\author{\fontfamily{LobsterTwo-LF}\selectfont{Alexander Deisting}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

and here the warnings:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/LobsterTwo-LF/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 13.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/LobsterTwo-LF/bx/n' in size <80> not availab
le
(Font)              size <35.83> substituted on input line 13.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/LobsterTwo-LF/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 13.

[1{/usr/local/Cellar/texlive/20220321_3/share/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/updma
p/pdftex.map}] (./fonttest.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 44.17pt have occurred.


LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

I checked if the font may be missing in general from my machine, but I found it in the expected paths (based on my previous texlive 2020 installation). E.g. `/usr/local/Cellar/texlive/20220321_3/share/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/lobster2/` exists. Some round of googeling unfortunately did not help, hence my question here. (Overleaf has the same problem, I currently don't have a machine with an older version to re-test, so you have to take my word for it that it worked before ;) ) Any ideas ?

Comment: the message means that the fd-files are not found. So do you have `T1LobsterTwo-LF.fd` somewhere in your search path?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer kpsewhich T1Lbstr-LF.fd

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I did the make equivalent of "sudo updatedb" on mac, but I did not specifically add texlive paths to path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latex family name is Lbstr-LF

```
kpsewhich T1Lbstr-LF.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lobster2/T1Lbstr-LF.fd
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\newcommand*{\LobsterTwo}{\fontfamily{Lbstr-LF}\selectfont}

\title{\LobsterTwo{\fontsize{80}{60}\selectfont Texte}}
%\author{{\LobsterTwo Alexander Deisting} }
\author{\fontfamily{Lbstr-LF}\selectfont{Alexander Deisting}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: I believed the OP that it worked before ;-). Did the family name change?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I only have 2020/21/22 here, it hasn't changed there.  https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32722915#32722915

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer, David! That does the trick. For my understanding - when did the LobsterTwo-LF to Lbstr-LF take place ?

Comment: @deisting  on overleaf your version works in 2020 but not 2021  or 2022, here with a fully updated "final" 2020 it doesn't work. so sometime in the texlive 2020 cycle